# How to make segmented control with menu like in the Xcode toolbar

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol, segmentedcontrol

I'd like to add a segmented control with menu like in Xcode toolbar to my OS X app. It will switch between three screens and also needs to have some options in each screen in the form of menu.[image: picture of what I need to implement]

The standard segmented control does not allow "Select one" mode when I add menu to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is built in. In code, you can just use the `-setMenu:forSegment:` method of `NSSegmentedControl` (or `NSSegmentedCell`). In Interface Builder, just drag a menu from the Object library and drop it on the appropriate segment.

To allow the segment with a menu to be selected when being clicked, you may need to use a custom subclass of `NSSegmentedControl` which overrides `-startTrackingAt:inView:` to set the segment to selected before calling through to super.

Comment: It seem like I should roll my own subclass anyway to implement that behaviour, no way achieve the needed behaviour with standard controls...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish what you were looking for quite easily.

I set the `trackingMode` of the segmented control to `NSSegmentSwitchTrackingMomentary`

Then i created an IBAction for the segmented control:

```
- (IBAction)selectionChanged:(NSSegmentedControl *)sender {
    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:[NSApp mainMenu] withEvent:[NSApp currentEvent] forView:sender];
}
```

Then it looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: This is the most simple solution to your problem. If you want to do anything more special there you have to subclass the segmented control and work from there.